# 1D fft on 2nd dim on Armadillo complex matrix

Tags: fft, mex, armadillo

I need to compute the 1D fft of a cx_mat in it's second dimension. So say I have this matrix:

```
cx_mat A(randu(5,10),randu(5,10));
```

The MATLAB version would look like:

```
A_fft=fft(A,[],2);
```

How would I go about this in Armadillo?

I'm trying to keep this as fast as possible so I figure a for loop running through the columns would not be the best option.

I then saw the `.each_col` attribute and tried

```
cx_mat A_fft=A.each_col([](vec& a){fft(a);});
```

But that would not compile. Maybe that is correct but my syntax is wrong

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a complex vector as argument in the lambda function:

`cx_mat A_fft=A.each_col([](cx_vec& a){fft(a);});`

Comment: So simple! Thank you!

Comment: It's not quite right. Here [.each_col()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow) with a lambda function does an inplace operation on matrix `A`. In other words, `A` is modified.